# variable was not declare in the scope class in private can not be access by member function

Tags: c++, private-members

```
//This is the header file (header.h)
class about{

char w[10][40];

public:
void get(const char core[ ][2000], int num);


};
```

~
~

```
//This is the cpp file (program.cpp)
 #include "header.h"
 #include <cstring>


void about::get(const char core[ ][2000], int num){

char data[2000];


strcpy(w[0], data);


}
```

I'm getting `program.cpp:13: error: 'w' was not declared in this scope`

I'm trying to just do the strcpy from `data` which contain some info to `w` which is from the private section of the class and using the member function to access them.

I'm not sure if I forgot anything and why I can't access them.

### Thanks to the last answer from Sergey Vakulenko

The sequence of the **header file** is very important.

It should be

```
 #include <cstring>
 #include "header.h"
```

not

```
 #include "header.h"
 #include <cstring>
```

Comment: `#include "header.h"` from `program.cpp`?

Comment: Yes I did sorry forgot to include in the post.

Comment: http://ideone.com/Bj6VU, your code should compile.

Comment: @wroniasty could that be the main program from my professor has a problem?

Comment: hard to tell, maybe you are including a different "header.h" than you are showing us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add these headers to your cpp file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "nameofheader.h"
```

***Edit (more full explication ):***

for me, that exemple not give any error:

1.h:

```
class about{

char w[10][40];

public:
void get(const char core[ ][2000], int num);


};
```

1.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "1.h"
//This is the cpp file (program.cpp)

void about::get(const char core[ ][2000], int num){

char data[2000];


strcpy(w[0], data);


}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

return 0;
}
```

compled with g++:

g++ 1.cpp -o 1

Comment: I found out now and yes it makes a different in your code because of the sequence! the header file should be after not before.... I don't know why it makes a different, but now it works after changed.

Answer (score 1):

Your program, the way you are showing it to us here, should compile without problems:

[ideone.com/Bj6VU](http://ideone.com/Bj6VU)

If you want more help, you should make the all of the two files you are compiling (program.cpp and header.h) available.